# Save linux terminal content *as displayed* to file

Tags: linux, terminal, special-characters, control-characters

I used `screen -L` to capture the output of an `ipython` session. `ipython` does a ton of munging of its output to allow for overwrites of the display in the terminal, so the file is full of control codes as you'd expect, and these codes are visible, and the output unreadable, when viewing the file in a editor or with `more` or `less`.

However, `cat` and `head` process the control codes and so the view on the terminal is 'correct' in that it looks like the output of the original session.

What I'd like to do is capture the text *as displayed on the terminal* when I `cat` the file. Obviously `cat file > newfile` will just copy the file over with the control codes intact.

Things I've tried:

- `script` also captures the control codes.
- `less -R` is still garbled
- `less -r` makes the terminal utterly spazz

Comment: "`cat` and `head` process the control codes" – This is not correct (or is an unfortunate wording). `cat` and `head` _output_ these control codes, and the _terminal emulator_ processes (interprets) them.

Comment: For this, you need a piece of software that interprets these codes just like a terminal emulator does. Probably this means you need a terminal emulator. Check your terminal whether it lets you save the contents, quite a few do. Also `tmux` (a replacement for `screen`) has a `capture-pane` option which I'm not familiar with, but _might_ do what you're looking for.

Comment: @egmont yeah, that was just sloppy wording.

Comment: A non-scalable workaround is to increase the terminal buffer to the size of the file in question, `cat` the file, select all, and C&P into an editor. This is good enough for now.